# baloo_file_extr process extremely slows down computer for several minutes at startup with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: startup, baloo

on startup of my laptop (with 8GB RAM) it takes minutes until it is useable. With "top" I saw that the wait percentage is about 70 %.
I saw the process baloo_file_extr consuming some CPU, and it was listed with consuming about 200 GB (!!!) of virtual RAM. The hard-disk light was permanently on, so this matches. baloo seems to be some file indexing app for kde, but in Ubuntu we are using Gnome, aren't we?

- How is that even possible?
- can I safely disable it?
- howto disable?

Answer (score 2):

The command to disable Baloo on my Ubuntu 20.04 OS is:

```
balooctl disable
```

To verify its enable/disable status

```
balooctl status
```

To see the percent CPU time baloo, and other applications, are consuming enter this command when your computer slows:

```
LINES=20 top -b -n 2 -d .5 -w
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes true its file indexing and search tool/framework (basically daemon) for KDE .

You can `disable` , `suspend` or check `status` it using the following command
`balooctl -option`
For myself , using 20.04LTS Xubuntu ,
`balooctl disable` worked better than `suspend` option .

Answer (score 0):

To disable baloo: Open $HOME/.kde4/share/config/baloofilerc and change the option 'Indexing-Enabled=true' to 'Indexing-Enabled=false'

Comment: I'm using xubuntu (XFCE) and this config file doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry to hear, maybe you can use balooctl disable  etc.